# MPMovieVIewController shows blank screen

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

Yep, this is my code:

```
import Foundation

class FbVideoPostDetailedViewController: FbDetailedPostViewController {

    var mc = MPMoviePlayerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let movieURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        self.mc = MPMoviePlayerController.init(contentURL: movieURL)
        self.mc.allowsAirPlay = false
        self.mc.shouldAutoplay = true
        self.mc.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        self.mc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
        self.view.addSubview(self.mc.view)
        self.mc.fullscreen = true
        self.mc.play()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

I'm just trying to open video in fullscreen mode. Please guide me in right way because `FbVideoPostDetailedViewController` appears only as a blank screen and video wasn't play.

I have few outlets in `FbDetailedPostViewController` but I want even to start play in fullscreen at this point.

Comment: You are missing `self.mc.prepareToPlay()` before `self.mc.play()`

Comment: @drewpts are you aware that MP classes are deprecated in iOS9?

Comment: @iphonic thanks for your answer but I fixed that this way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: @Dumoko no, what should I do for compliance with iOS9?

Comment: @Dumoko
Ok, I found about AVPlayerViewController :) Thanks